# .Net Web Forms testing execution time of calls behind response time

Tags: asp.net, performance

I wish to performance test several web pages (response time) and time the 'Execution calls' behind each page which compose the overall response time.

I am writing these out directly to the Trace, what is the best way of timing each individual call ?

Comment: What are you using for calculating executing time for a module ? It should be [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for this.